# boost::spirit: qi::rule or struct containing a qi::rule as parsing result

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

What I'm trying to do is creating a parser from a ABNF grammar file at runtime. I already implemented all ABNF rules inside a qi::grammar like these two:

```
typedef /*qi::rule or struct containing qi::rule*/ parserRule

    [...] //all other ABNF rules according to RFC 5234

    rule =
            (
                    rulename[qi::_a = qi::_1] >>
                    definedAs >>
                    elements[qi::_b = qi::_1] >>
                    cNl
            )[qi::_val = px::bind(&AbnfParserFactory::fromRule, &factory, qi::_a, qi::_b)];


    rulelist =
            +(
                    rule[px::push_back(qi::_a, qi::_1)] |
                    (*cWsp >> cNl)
             ) >>
             eps[qi::_val = px::bind(&AbnfParserFactory::fromRulelist, &factory, qi::_a)];


qi::rule<Iterator, std::map<std::string, parserRule>(), qi::locals<std::vector<parserRule> > >  rulelist;
qi::rule<Iterator, parserRule(), qi::locals<std::string>, qi::locals<parserRule> >              rule;
[...] // all other ABNF rules
```

Inside the `ParserFactory`, a new qi::rule is created according to the read in grammar:

```
std::map<std::string, ReturnType> fromRulelist(std::vector<ReturnType> &rules)
{
    // return a map with <rulename, rule>
};

parserRule fromRule(std::string &name, parserRule &rule)
{
    //name the rule an return it
    rule.name(name);
    return rule;
};
```

The question is about the type of `parserRule`.

If I use qi::rule as type (like I usually intended), I will loose every rule name that was assigned in the `ParserFactory`(like in `fromRule`). I guess this is caused by the way spirit works internally (`=` operator always creates a new, unnamed rule. And the `=` is used to assign the px::bind function result)

If I however try to wrap my qi::rule into a struct to avoid this issue, I am no longer able to compile my code with spirit debugging. Here is what i tried:

```
typedef qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> FactoryRuleType;
struct parserRule
{
    FactoryRuleType mRule;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
 parserRule,
(FactoryRuleType, mRule)
)

[...] //rule definitions like above

debug(rule);
debug(rulelist);
[...] //debug all other rules
```

This will give me a load of compile errors (which is WAY to long to post here). I have searched my ass of for days trying to solve this, but without any luck. I hope I mentioned enough details.

Any help is appreciated.

Compile output excerpt:

```
/usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp:295:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Left, class Right> const typename boost::proto::detail::enable_binary<boost::proto::domainns_::deduce_domain, boost::proto::detail::not_a_grammar, boost::mpl::or_<boost::proto::is_extension<Arg>, boost::proto::is_extension<Right> >, boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left, Left&, Right&>::type boost::proto::exprns_::operator<<(Left&, Right&) [with Left = std::basic_ostream<char>; Right = const boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >]’:
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1226:17:   required from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::print_attribute_debug<Out, T, Enable>::call_impl3(Out&, const T_&, mpl_::false_) [with T_ = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Out = std::basic_ostream<char>; T = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Enable = void; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1242:67:   required from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::print_attribute_debug<Out, T, Enable>::call_impl2(Out&, const T_&, mpl_::false_) [with T_ = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Out = std::basic_ostream<char>; T = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Enable = void; mpl_::false_ = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1277:52:   required from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::print_attribute_debug<Out, T, Enable>::call_impl(Out&, const T_&, mpl_::true_) [with T_ = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Out = std::basic_ostream<char>; T = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Enable = void; mpl_::true_ = mpl_::bool_<true>]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1283:52:   required from ‘static void boost::spirit::traits::print_attribute_debug<Out, T, Enable>::call(Out&, const T&) [with Out = std::basic_ostream<char>; T = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >; Enable = void]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1303:53:   required from ‘void boost::spirit::traits::print_attribute(Out&, const T&) [with Out = std::basic_ostream<char>; T = boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/support/attributes.hpp:1196:57:   [ skipping 34 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:7:   required from ‘boost::function4<R, T1, T2, T3, T4>::function4(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::debug_handler<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::simple_trace>; R = bool; T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&; T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1069:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::debug_handler<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::simple_trace>; R = bool; T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&; T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1124:5:   required from ‘typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>::operator=(Functor) [with Functor = boost::spirit::qi::debug_handler<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >, boost::spirit::unused_type, boost::spirit::qi::simple_trace>; R = bool; T0 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T1 = const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&; T2 = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&; T3 = const boost::spirit::unused_type&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3)>&>::type = boost::function<bool(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<FactoryReturnType&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<> >&, const boost::spirit::unused_type&)>&]’
/usr/include/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/debug_handler.hpp:122:13:   required from ‘void boost::spirit::qi::debug(boost::spirit::qi::rule<Iterator, T1, T2, T3, T4>&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >; T1 = FactoryReturnType(); T2 = boost::spirit::unused_type; T3 = boost::spirit::unused_type; T4 = boost::spirit::unused_type]’
../src/AbnfReader.hpp:350:14:   required from ‘AbnfRules<Iterator>::AbnfRules() [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]’
../src/AbnfReader.cpp:27:12:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/proto/operators.hpp:295:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::proto::detail::enable_binary<boost::proto::domainns_::deduce_domain, boost::proto::detail::not_a_grammar, boost::mpl::or_<boost::proto::is_extension<std::basic_ostream<char> >, boost::proto::is_extension<const boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> > >, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >, boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left, std::basic_ostream<char>&, const boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::basic_string<char>()> >&>’
make: *** [src/AbnfReader.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Can you include a SSCCE that demonstrates your problem _in a succinct way_? Also, I'm getting half a vibe that you want to compose grammars dynamically. This road is fraught with danger as Boost Proto/Boost Phoenix's expression templates are not designed for value semantics (they prefer to live as temporaries only). You can search my answers for the keyword `deep_copy` for a taste of the many problems you will run into.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have to compose grammars dynamically at runtime. To make sure that this would be possible, I already wrote a bunch of test snippets which worked as intended. So I think my approach is possible (although it might not be the best). I will take a look at your answers and try to clean up my question if I have the time. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is awkward. While trying to write a SSCCE like sehe suggested, I discovered that my approach was actually working all along. And I went through so much trouble trying to solve this... :C

Here is a working example of what I was trying to do. Although it works, the behaviour is still a bit odd, which is the reason I believed it does not work this way.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

typedef qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string()> parserRule;


namespace std
{
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const parserRule& val);
}
std::ostream& std::operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const parserRule& val)
{
    stream << "RULE( " << val.name();
    stream << " )";
    return stream;
}

class Factory
{
public:
    Factory(){}
    parserRule createParser(std::string str)
    {
        parserRule r;
        r = qi::char_(str);
        r.name("FactoryRule");
        std::cout << r.name() << " now parses >" + str + "<" << std::end;
        return r;
    }
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct TestGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, parserRule()>
{

    TestGrammar() : TestGrammar::base_type(start, "Test grammar")
    {
        start = stringRule.alias();
        stringRule =    (
                ascii::char_("'") >>
                *(ascii::char_ - ascii::char_("'"))[qi::_a += qi::_1] >>
                ascii::char_("'")
        )[qi::_val = px::bind(&Factory::createParser, &factory, qi::_a)];

        start.name("Start");
        stringRule.name("StringRule");

        qi::debug(start);       // shows "RULE( unnamed-rule )"
        qi::debug(stringRule);  // shows "RULE( unnamed-rule )"
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator, parserRule() > start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, parserRule(), qi::locals<std::string> > stringRule;
    Factory factory;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator iterator_type;
    typedef TestGrammar<iterator_type> TGrammar;


    TGrammar test_parser;

    std::string test = "parse THIS!";
    std::string input = "'"+test+"'";
    parserRule result;

    std::string::const_iterator iter = input.begin();
    std::string::const_iterator end = input.end();

    bool r = parse(iter, end, test_parser, result);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "1st Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::string rest(iter, end);
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "1st Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "stopped at: \"" << rest << "\"\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }

    iterator_type first(test.begin()), last(test.end());

    qi::debug(result); //shows correct rule name
    r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, result, boost::spirit::ascii::space);

    if (r && iter == end)
    {
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "2nd Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::string rest(first, last);
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
        std::cout << "2nd Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "stopped at: \"" << rest << "\"\n";
        std::cout << "-------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
FactoryRule now parses >parse THIS!<
<Start>
  <try>'parse THIS!'</try>
  <StringRule>
    <try>'parse THIS!'</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[RULE( unnamed-rule )]]</attributes><locals>(parse THIS!)</locals>
  </StringRule>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[RULE( unnamed-rule )]]</attributes>
</Start>
-------------------------
1st Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
<FactoryRule>
  <try>parse THIS!</try>
  <success>arse THIS!</success>
  <attributes>[[p]]</attributes>
</FactoryRule>
-------------------------
2nd Parsing succeeded
-------------------------
```

As you can see, debugging the rules `start` and `stringRule` will always display "RULE( unnamed-rule )" as attributes. This made me believe that the assigned rule name was lost due to the use of the `=`-operator when assigning the `px::bind` result. Since debugging the `result` rule shows the correct name, I assume that the "unnamed-rule" output simply does not show the correct, FINAL synthesized attribute, but rather the current, "empty" one.

BIG SHAME ON ME for immediately panicking when seeing the "unnamed-rule" and spending WAY to many days trying to solve this and even asking here WITHOUT actually testing the whole thing by debugging the `result` rule.

Thanks for trying to help me anyway. I hope this might at least be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues can be at play here, from just experience, without further code:

1. single-element adapted structs pose problems, see: [link coming]
2. debug information requires specialization of a debug printing traits (that falls back to `ostream` streaming). Obviously this hasn't been done for `qi::rule`. So, either add that.

   Maybe, just maybe you could make the containing struct iostream-able to avoid it (but I fear that the fusion adaptation might take priority. It's worh a try)

---

> Q. Yes, you are correct. I have to compose grammars dynamically at runtime. To make sure that this would be possible, I already wrote a bunch of test snippets which worked as intended.

- To be very blunt: Spirit is not the tool for that. Spirit is a tool that generates *statically compiled* grammars from "praser expressions", which are expression templates. The whole purpose is to be compiletime and use static polymorphism with full optimization. I'd suggest maybe creating a set of runtime-polymorphic parser components (that you can, in turn, implement using Spirit :)) and compose your dynamic grammars out of them instead.

  A sort-of possible middle ground would be using `qi::lazy` with a set of predefined immutable "atom" rules (so not composed on the fly) and compose your parser using these "atom" rules by reference.
- Basically, as long as you **don't** try to dynamically compose *expression templates* (but rather, ready made type-erased non-terminals) you should be fine.

  If you need more, you'll be in UB-land in no time. Some of the time you will be able to fight your way out using `boost::proto::deep_copy`, but there are limitations to this.